# Persisting user logins in mobile app through ASP.NET Web API and Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET **MVC5** Web application that uses the Identity framework for authentication and authorization. Here is the screenshot of identity-related tables:

[image]

Now we are to develop a mobile app. The mobile app will be using the same database as the ASP.NET MVC5 Web App but not directly. It will be using an ASP.NET Core Web API written on top of the same database.

The issue is persisting user logins in mobile application so that a user does not have to login everytime. They just login once and use this app. I am looking for something where the user will get authenticated through API and a user token will be returned in the mobile app to prevent their session to expire as long as the token is there. But I am confused and not sure where to store this token and related info such as expiration time etc.

Which library/framework should be used in such a scenario?

Comment: You can see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24759150/mobile-app-authentication-and-authorization-with-asp-net) may helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IdentityServer](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that is recommended [Oauth2](https://oauth.net/2/) library by Microsoft

it can also [integrate with AspNetCore](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/aspnet_identity.html) Authentication System