# Email with url back to asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

Situation:
I building an application for users to fill out a form.  The data then is sent to a database.  An email is sent to the users manager with the data and a link back to the application where a form is then populated with the data.

Question:
Where can I find the information which speaks on how to get the URL/Link (with recordID that populates a page.) back to the applications (also what is this action called?)?  The email works fine... I can send a url with a link to a website.

Not asking for the code... just where I can find the information...

Thanks

Comment: Is there a name for this action...?

Answer (score 0):

Lets see if I understood:

1. User fills form with data and submits
2. Data is saved
3. An email is sent with link
4. Clicking the link loads the form with the above data

If that's the case, then the easiest way to do this is:

1. When saving the data, [create a token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643735/how-to-generate-a-unique-token-which-expires-after-24-hours) for it.
2. The link sent in the email will use the token: http://yourdomain.com?token=[TOKEN]
3. When handling the above request, query the data according to the token, and return a form populated by it.

Comment: Is there a name for this action...?

Comment: I think it's derived from the concept of [Token Based Authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592534/what-is-token-based-authentication), there you generate the token after a successful login and the client uses it in each request (as a header) to access his data.