# How to set Email conformation link token expire after 10 minutes in Asp.net Identity

Tags: c#, access-token, asp.net-identity-2

Have tried to set the Expiry time for the Email conformation link which is sending after user registration, the link token should expire after 10 mins. have used the code but even after 10 mins user can still access the link, here is my code,

```
var userManager = GetUserManager();
userManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User,int(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ConfirmEmail"))
{
    TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
};
```

Comment: When user clicks the link does Token Validation happens? Are you doing manually or leaving it to the Identity Framework?

Comment: When user clicks the link have tested with `
            var result =  userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(Id, purpose, token);` but getting false all the time even having valid token.

Comment: There is a nice solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643735/how-to-generate-a-unique-token-which-expires-after-24-hours)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is that there is an error in your syntax.

```
userManager.UserTokenProvider = 
    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User,int(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ConfirmEmail"))
```

is missing a closing bracket.

```
userManager.UserTokenProvider =       here v
    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User,int>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ConfirmEmail"))
```

then you have to call

```
userManager.UserTokenProvider.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
```

The way you are doing it does not modify the TokenLifespan of the UserTokenProvider that is binded to your UserManager but some other attribute.