# Any way i can create access token manually (without identity server 4 or similar stuff) in .net

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, access-token

I need to generate Oauth2.0 Access token. in my asp.net core web api.
Any way i can create it without a need of integrating whole identity server 4 or similar thing?
For unique token i was looking for 
[how to generate a unique token which expires after 24 hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643735/how-to-generate-a-unique-token-which-expires-after-24-hours)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

able to do it using RSASecurity Details are mentioned in my other post [How to create RsaSecurityKey from Public/Private Key Pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60428199/how-to-create-rsasecuritykey-from-public-private-key-pair)