# C# How to generate token by code which will be valid for next 5 minutes

Tags: c#

Here i have code which generate token valid for 24 hours but i am looking for a logic which generate token number will be valid for 5 minutes. i search google but found no idea. so please some one share any idea would be appreciated. thanks

```
public static string GenerateToken()
{
    int month = DateTime.Now.Month;
    int day = DateTime.Now.Day;
    string token = ((day * 100 + month) * 700 + day * 13).ToString();
    return token;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the kind of implementation you're looking for, but take a look at
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14644367/7902641).

**Excerpt:**

> Basic example of creating a unique token containing a time stamp:
>
> ```
> byte[] time = BitConverter.GetBytes(DateTime.UtcNow.ToBinary());
> byte[] key = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
> string token = Convert.ToBase64String(time.Concat(key).ToArray());
> ```
>
> To decode the token to get the creation time:
>
> ```
> byte[] tokenByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(token);
> DateTime when = DateTime.FromBinary(BitConverter.ToInt64(tokenByteArray, 0));
> if (when < DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5)) {
>   // too old
> }
> ```

(I changed the decode section to match your requirement for a 5 minute token invalidation, and changed the original "data" variable to "tokenByteArray" for clarity.)

---

### Clarifications in response to comment request

**Drilling down into why we use `BitConverter.ToInt64(tokenByteArray, 0)`:**

This whole implementation relies on that final deserialization operation which allows us to rebuild a copy of the original `DateTime` object that we started with.

This rebuilding / deserialization is accomplished by calling the static `DateTime.FromBinary()` method, which takes a 64-bit signed integer (or `long` data type) as its parameter.

Since we originally converted our `DateTime` object down into a `byte[]`, we need to deserialize the `string` token that we generated to extract our `DateTime` value. And seeing that `DateTime.FromBinary()` requires a 64-bit signed integer parameter, we need to convert our string token's `byte[]` by calling `BitConverter.ToInt64(tokenByteArray, 0)` - (the 0 just denotes where in the array to start converting).

Now we just feed the converted 64-bit integer into the `DateTime.FromBinary()` method, and we're done.

### Example / Fiddle

- [My .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6ezG7F)

### Resources:

- [BitConverter.ToInt64() - Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.toint64?view=netcore-3.1#System_BitConverter_ToInt64_System_Byte___System_Int32_)
- [DateTime.FromBinary() - Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.frombinary?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: i will check your code and let you know. thanks for the answer.

Comment: this line not clear `DateTime.FromBinary(BitConverter.ToInt64(data, 0));` please explain when you get time.

Comment: Sure - updated my answer with some more details and an example fiddle.

Comment: thank you sir for clarification.

Comment: How to validate this token ? this time checking logic not workig. `if (when < DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5)) {
  // too old
}`

Comment: I've updated my .NET Fiddle with a validation example. You can run any DateTime comparison operations that you want (not just "AddMinutes(-5)") against the DateTime you extracted from the token.

Answer (score 1):

If you use identity. You can implement this

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
...   
public class SomeTokenAuthenticationService : IAuthenticateService
{
    private readonly TokenManagement _tokenManagement;
 
    public SomeTokenAuthenticationService(IOptions<TokenManagement> tokenManagement)
        {
            _tokenManagement = tokenManagement.Value;
        }
    
public string GenerateToken(ClaimsIdentity identity){
                var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
                var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_tokenManagement.Secret));
                var credentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        
                var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    _tokenManagement.Issuer,
                    _tokenManagement.Audience,
                    notBefore:now,
                    claims:identity.Claims,
                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(_tokenManagement.AccessExpiration),
                    signingCredentials: credentials
                );
                var tokenjwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwtToken);
        
                return $"Bearer {tokenjwt}";
            }}
```

also you need to add an option in appsettings.Development.json

```
"tokenManagement": {
    "secret": "Secret : in the 1eujsjjdjodjdjodfjodjojofjfdjdj 1234567891",
    "issuer": "test.user",
    "audience": "SampleAudience",
    "accessExpiration": 30,//minutes
    "refreshExpiration": 60
  }
```

Comment: https://garywoodfine.com/asp-net-core-2-2-jwt-authentication-tutorial/

Comment: i am looking for small independent routine which generate a arbitrary number which will be valid upto 5 minute. i am not really after identity.

Comment: string token =  DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5).ToString(); return token; -?

Comment: sorry it is not so easy. if i found out the logic i will share with you.