# Encrypt URL in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, security, url, encryption

My site is in asp.net 3.5 and C#. I am sending link to my user through mail, now I want to send each user a specific URL. So instead of sending the clear text I want to send link with encrypted string URL, which I will decrypt on my home page.
Like instead of `www.mysite.aspx\mypage?userId=12` I'll send `www.mysite.aspx\mypage?UserId=)@kasd12`
and the same I'll decrypt on my page so that I'll get the `userId = 12`.

Please let me know if my approach is correct and not and how can I encrypt & decrypt the string in simplest and easier manner.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple 2 way encryption for C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165808/simple-2-way-encryption-for-c) or [Encrypt/Decrypt string in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165808/simple-2-way-encryption-for-c)

Comment: @Jørn Thanks, I've deleted my suggestion to use a GUID. This thread was the clincher! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643445/how-easily-can-you-guess-a-guid-that-might-be-generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a random string value instead of encryption/decryption :) And make it at least 6 or 7 characters long. Store the the value in the database and once the value is received through a query string, run a SQL query to do whatever for the corresponding row :)

```
Page_Load()

string x = Request.QueryString["UserID"];

SqlCommand x = new SqlCommand("UPDATE UserTable SET UserStatus='Activated' WHERE RandomKey='x'", connection);
```

Comment: Rather than a 6 or 7 character string, use a Guid.

Comment: @Ben - I had the same bright idea only to discover that it wasn't so bright! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643445/how-easily-can-you-guess-a-guid-that-might-be-generated

Comment: Just because guids are not crypto graphically secure does notmean they are not fit for this purpose.  They are not suitable to use as a cryptograhpic key as they could as the data could be decrypted by generating millions of likely guids.  This atack is not feasable in the context of a querystring key as you would have to make millions of http requests in a short period of time

Answer (score 2):

isn't it more appropiate to generate a temporary access key?

Comment: With > 50 reputation points, you should be able to post this kind of follow-up questions as comments to the question rather than as a void answer :)

Comment: @Jørn I'd say that is a valid answer. The OP asks "Please let me know if my approach is correct"

Comment: this is an answer on "Please let me know if my approach is correct". Only I'm not saying he should use the more common approach of generating unique "hard-to-guess" access codes, I'm trying to let him think about wether this is what he really wants.... security through obscurity is always a bad thing btw :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/QueryStringEncryptionNET.aspx) page is what your after. Its basically a HttpModule that can be used to encrypt querystrings.